# Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:65185

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have following problem when I'm trying to run chromedriver:

```
Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:65185
```

Code is very simple:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

-I have netcore 3.1 project with Nunit;

-Visual studio 19 is launched with admins permissions;

-I've already tried to use chromedriver full path in chromedriver initialization it wasn't help;

-Port isn't occupied by any other processes;

-Chromedriver launching successfully via command line so it is valid;

-I don't think that there is some proxy on my workstation

-Localhost and 127.0.0.1 are uncommented in hosts file

-Tried to use firefox driver - the same issue

Comment: Have an important update. On my workstation I have windows proxy, disabling it solving problem with launching webdriver, but working site become unavailable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason was in windows proxy settings, I had to add localhost as proxy exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You may consider downgrading your .Net Core version to 2.1. Once this was the solution for me.

Comment: Weird thing is that on my home PC I have the same settings and all works fine. So I don't think that 3.1 version is the reason of this issue

Comment: And yeah, I've tried to switch to 2.1 - still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was coming from a setting on the Chrome Service itself.

My code was as follows:

```
var chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
if(!chromeService.IsRunning)
     chromeService.Start();
```

Once I removed the setting for 'SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation' the Service started without the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (but it was in Firefox), as banal as it seems, it solved it by putting Visual Studio to run in admin mode, because he was without privileged access to run on the port he wanted